# insert images in google docs (or pdf) coming from google spreadsheets?

Tags: image, url, google-sheets-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have Google spreadsheets with several raws and lines.

I take each lines of each raw of my google spreadsheet and i generate a pdf with it based on a Google Docs template.

In one raw, I have url's from pictures stored into Google Drive, and I want to display picture into my pdf but i dont succeed, I just can display the url link , I tried this tuto (https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f84831455dea5c394e48caaee0058b26) but I dont succeed.

I tried to display the image into cell of spreadsheet and to send it into my pdf, but it doesnt work too, it display " Cellimage"text but nothing much..

Is somebody has an idea please ?Thank you very much ?

---

```
/*

PDF Creator - Email all responses
=================================

When you click "Create PDF > Create a PDF for each row" this script 
constructs a PDF for each row in the attached GSheet. The value in the 
"File Name" column is used to name the file and - if there is a 
value - it is emailed to the recipient in the "Email" column.



*/

// Config
// ------


// 1. Create a GDoc template and put the ID here

var TEMPLATE_ID = 'MY TEMPLATE ID IN GOOGLE DOCS'



// 2. You can specify a name for the new PDF file here, or leave empty to use the 
// name of the template or specify the file name in the sheet

var PDF_FILE_NAME = ''

// 3. If an email address is specified you can email the PDF

var EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'Rapport de contrôle'
var EMAIL_BODY = 'Bonjour, suite au contrôle de raccordement de votre installation, veuillez trouver ci-joint le compte-rendu en version PDF. Vous en souhaitant une bonne réception.Bien Cordialement. '

// 4. If a folder ID is specified here this is where the PDFs will be located

var RESULTS_FOLDER_ID = 'FOLDER WHERE I SEND MY PDF'

// Constants
// ---------

// You can pull out specific columns values 
var FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME = 'data-Nom'
var EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME = 'data-Email'

// The format used for any dates 
var DATE_FORMAT = 'dd/MM/yyyy';

/**
 * Eventhandler for spreadsheet opening - add a menu.
 */

function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu('[ Create PDFs ]')
    .addItem('Create a PDF for each row', 'createPdfs')
    .addToUi()

} // onOpen()

/**  
 * Take the fields from each row in the active sheet
 * and, using a Google Doc template, create a PDF doc with these
 * fields replacing the keys in the template. The keys are identified
 * by having a % either side, e.g. %Name%.
 */

function createPdfs() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

  if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') {    
    ui.alert('TEMPLATE_ID needs to be defined in code.gs')
    return
  }

  // Set up the docs and the spreadsheet access

  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID)
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var allRows = activeSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var headerRow = allRows.shift()

  // Create a PDF for each row

  allRows.forEach(function(row) {
  
    createPdf(templateFile, headerRow, row)
    
    // Private Function
    // ----------------
  
    /**
     * Create a PDF
     *
     * @param {File} templateFile
     * @param {Array} headerRow
     * @param {Array} activeRow
     */
  
    function createPdf(templateFile, headerRow, activeRow) {
      
      var headerValue
      var activeCell
      var ID = null
      var recipient = null
      var copyFile
      var numberOfColumns = headerRow.length
      var copyFile = templateFile.makeCopy()      
      var copyId = copyFile.getId()
      var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
      var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection()
           
      // Replace the keys with the spreadsheet values and look for a couple
      // of specific values
     
      for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
        
        headerValue = headerRow[columnIndex]
        activeCell = activeRow[columnIndex]
        activeCell = formatCell(activeCell);
                
        copyBody.replaceText('<<' + headerValue + '>>', activeCell)
        
        if (headerValue === FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME) {
        
          ID = activeCell
          
        } else if (headerValue === EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME) {
        
          recipient = activeCell
        }
      }
      
      // Create the PDF file
        
      copyDoc.saveAndClose()
      var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'))  
      copyFile.setTrashed(true)
    
      // Rename the new PDF file
    
      if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {
      
        newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)
        
      } else if (ID !== null){
    
        newFile.setName(ID)
      }
      
      // Put the new PDF file into the results folder
      
      if (RESULTS_FOLDER_ID !== '') {
      
        DriveApp.getFolderById(RESULTS_FOLDER_ID).addFile(newFile)
        DriveApp.removeFile(newFile)
      }

      // Email the new PDF

      if (recipient !== null) {
      
        MailApp.sendEmail(
          recipient, 
          EMAIL_SUBJECT, 
          EMAIL_BODY,
          {attachments: [newFile]})
      }
    
    } // createPdfs.createPdf()

  })

  ui.alert('New PDF files created')

  return
  
  // Private Functions
  // -----------------
  
  /**
  * Format the cell's value
  *
  * @param {Object} value
  *
  * @return {Object} value
  */
  
  function formatCell(value) {
    
    var newValue = value;
    
    if (newValue instanceof Date) {
      
      newValue = Utilities.formatDate(
        value, 
        Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 
        DATE_FORMAT);
        
    } else if (typeof value === 'number') {
    
      newValue = Math.round(value * 100) / 100
    }
    
    return newValue;
        
  } // createPdf.formatCell()
  
} // createPdfs()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot image your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide your current script, the explanation of the current issue of your script, and the sample input and output situation you expect?

Comment: Hello Tanaike, thank you very much for your reply, this is my code:

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. At first, I deeply apologize that my sample script was not useful for your situation. When I saw your script, I cannot understand about the relationship between your script and my sample script. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about it?